# Почему "бородавка" — от слова "борода"?

Tags: этимология

Заинтересовал вопрос: а почему, собственно, "бородавка" происходит от слова "борода"? На бороде их не бывает, а подбородок — далеко не единственное место, где они могут возникнуть (по-моему, на руках они появляются куда чаще).
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У бородавки есть дальний родственник вред (веред), что означает нарыв, болячка, сравнить: бередить.  Исходное слово: vordava,AV - это суффикс, К - уменьшительный суффикс.

Answer (score 1):

Почему «борода»? Скорее всего, из-за внешнего сходства, ведь бородавка представляет собой пучок нитевидных кожных отросточков (с)